# Using NSPredicate to fetch exact NSDate from NSManagedObjectContect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nspredicate, fetch

I'm trying to fetch results of my entity "MeterReading", which has two properties, "timestamp" and "reading". "timestamp" is an NSDate. I'm now trying to fetch an object with an exact date.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MeterReading" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];
NSLog(@"%f", [self.timestamp timeIntervalSince1970]);

NSPredicate *pre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp == %@", self.timestamp];
NSLog(@"%@", pre);
[request setPredicate:pre];
```

Now, self.timestamp is passed to another ViewController beforehand, the NSLog shows:

> 1290264372.210091

The NSPredicate logs

> timestamp == CAST(311957172.210091, "NSDate")

First question: Why aren't the two numbers the same?

Second and more important question: In the ManagedContext, I have four entries with dates. If I use "<=" instead of "==", I do get results with a date smaller than the one I passed, including the one I want to have. Why can't I get the one single date with the "==" operator? Can this be related to precision of my dates?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the same issue as floating-point equality checks being inherently unsafe. As floating-point values get passed around, converted, used in arithmetic, etc., they lose accuracy bit by bit. You may have to use a more complex predicate that instead checks for dates within a certain tolerance; for instance,

```
NSArray *timestamps = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
    [self.timestamp dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1],
    [self.timestamp dateByAddingTimeInterval:1],
    nil
];

NSPredicate *pre = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"timestamp BETWEEN %@", timestamps];
```

which would get you any objects matching your date plus or minus one second.

Comment: that almost worked, thanks! passing the array brought up an error, but i passed two nsdates manually to the predicate and now it works. :)

Comment: Oops, sorry about that! Glad it helped, though.

Comment: Note that this example won't work with core data. You need to use something like this: http://zdam.posterous.com/core-data-fetch-by-date

Answer (score 3):

> First question: Why aren't the two numbers the same?

Internally, `NSDate` seems to store a timestamp relative to January 1, 2001, and not January 1, 1970. The number `311957172.210091` probably is the number of seconds since 01/01/2001.

> Why can't I get the one single date with the "==" operator? Can this be related to precision of my dates?

I don't know. Have you inspected the SQLite file directly to see which timestamps are stored there?

Comment: i'm getting the timestamp from my store, pass it to another view controller and try to delete it there. therefore i'm trying to fetch the same object; i passed the timestamp beforehand. that's the weird thing.

is there another way to delete an managed object without getting that object beforehand?

Comment: Why do you pass the timestamp around and not the object itself? No need to fetch it again.

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I bet the numbers will match if you used `[self.timestamp timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]` instead of since 1970.

For your second question, my hunch is that the date in the managed object storage is not exactly the same as self.timestamp.  For instance, could it be that the stored date only contains a day and not time?  You might need to do some rounding to get those to match.

Comment: Actually, I'm using the timestamp or date directly from the managed object, pass it to another view controller, do some other stuff and want to delete it again. therefore i need the object to delete it from the context, and i don't know any other way to delete an object before fetching it again.
so, it should be the same date i'm using.